# Java strange behaviour: Program cancels but no Exception is thrown

Tags: java

I have a very strange behavior in my application(a vlcj base music player). I use a **ConcurrentHashMap** to cache information about an artist.

If i call **get** on the HashMap the program seems to stop, but no exception is thrown. The "a" has been printed out, **but the "b" has never been printed out**.

In a separate thread i ran a deadlock check but it, no deadlock was detected, and I'm very sure that I don't use the Cache in another thread.

```
public void newMedia(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    MusicListItem item = this.playListModel.getActiveItem();

    System.out.println("a");
    // cachedArtists = ConcurrentHashMap<String, Artist>
    Artist artist = this.cachedArtists.get(item.getArtist());
    System.out.println("b");
}
```

Did i found a JVM-Bug?

**Here is my JVM**:
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

Comment: does it hang after printing a? if yes what does thread dump show when it hangs after printing a ?

Comment: I can tell you right away that you *didn't* find a JVM bug.

Comment: why do you use ConcurrentHashMap if you do not use it in any other thread ?

Comment: Wrap it in a `try catch` with a `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch section. That'll tell you for certain if anything is happening.

Comment: it may happen that you source `java` file isn't in sync with `class` file or are you sure program exits? It would be good if you post some more content of your code `item.getArtist` etc..

Comment: @JigarJoshi, no the programm does not hang up, it continous running.

Comment: @gregory561 first I used a HashMap but then I found out that the problem maybe is caused by a deadlock, so I changed it to a ConcurrentHashMap. But that didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: @Chris: Woow, I put a try catch block arround the code and got the following error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to de.roth.jsona.artist.Artist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Chris said, I put a try catch block arround the code and indeed I got a JavaClassCastEXception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to de.roth.jsona.artist.Artist

Answer (score 1):

I see three things that could go wrong here, you might want to check whether they can actually happen (I don't have enough context to tell):

- `cachedArtists` might be `null`
- `item` might be `null` (there is not active item in the playListModel)
- `item.getArtist()` might error out (exception or `System.exit()`)

Most of these cases involve an exception being thrown so you would expect to see a stacktrace, but maybe this is swallowed somewhere up in the callstack - again, I don't have the context to tell. Best follow Chris's advice to figure out by wrapping the offending line into a `try...catch` block yourself and print the stack trace of any exception manually.

Comment: Yeah Chris got it! An Exception was thrown but was not printed. With the try...catch I figured it out...

Answer (score 0):

If the program just hangs (does not terminate), I'd guess that `item.getArtist()` blocks. Verify via

```
System.out.println("a");
Artist key = item.getArtist();
System.out.println("b");
Artist artist = this.cachedArtists.get(key);
System.out.println("c");
```

(getting an artist via an Artist(?) smells of Munchhausen pattern btw)